# Why are my notification's not firing in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to set up my notifications in my SwiftUI app, but it doesn't work when I test it in the simulator.

Currently, I request Permission and setup notifications from one of my onboarding cards that are only shown on the first app launch. Once the user has seen the onboarding, that information is stored in user defaults and the onboarding never shows up again.

My goal is to display one notification, every morning at 10 am.

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct OBCardView: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    let card: OnboardCard
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("Background")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            
            VStack {
                
                
                Image(card.image)
                    
                
                Text(card.title)
                    
                Text(card.text)
                    
                if card.notification != nil {
                    Button("Get Notified") {
                        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                            if success {
                                print("All set!")
                                self.configureAlerts()
                                withAnimation {
                                    isShowing = false
                                }
                            } else if let error = error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                   
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func configureAlerts() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        
        center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = "Your daily text is waiting for you."
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

        dateComponents.hour = 10    // 14:00 hours
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
                 dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        
        let randomIdentifier = UUID().uuidString
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: randomIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        center.add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When testing this code with the simulator, the Permission Request window pops up, however, when I reset my clock to 10 am the next day, nothing happens. Why is it so? Could it be because I trigger "SetupNotification" in the onboarding instead of the home page?

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind app delegate? Also, under which function would you add it?

Comment: If I want it to be every day, would you list out every single day of the week, or is there a more efficient way of being more explicit? @PranavKasetti

Comment: follow the guide [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-set-local-alerts-using-unnotificationcenter) - you're missing the last step.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The last part talks about custom buttons, which is not something I'm interested in. Could you please detail your reply? Thanks! @PranavKasetti

Comment: no it doesn't, you need to read the whole context. you need to call the completion handler inside the delegate method - that's the only requirement

Comment: Leave the app! The notification does not fire if the app is in the foreground! I spent 1h to find that out....